# how to find unique values in a sql table and create a consolidated view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table which if I simplify looks similar to this

| login_code_id | login_purpose_type |
| --- | --- |
| A | maintenance |
| A | review |
| C | review |
| C | terminate |
| A | review |
| B | scan |

I have a pretty large dataset in a form of SQL table. Now the Question is what should I do to group this by login_code_id where I can see what are the different kinds of login_purpose_type against a unique login_code_id and how many time each login_purpose_type is occuring for each login_code_id. Finally store the result in a new table, which is totally confusing me. How should I approach this? Sorry for being ignorant if what I am asking is very simple. I am very new to this. I am using phpmyadmin to create table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CREATE TABLE from the results of your query. (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html)

```
CREATE TABLE summary 
SELECT login_code_id, login_purpose_type, COUNT(login_purpose_type) AS cnt 
FROM <old_table_name> 
GROUP BY login_code_id, login_purpose_type;
```

will give you a table with the following structure:

```
 login_code_id | login_purpose_type | cnt

 ======================================= 
 A             |  maintenance       |  5
 ----------------------------------------
 A             |  review            |  3
 ----------------------------------------
 B             |  review            |  2
```

In this table, every row shows how often a given login_purpose_type occured for a given login_code_id.

If you really want to have a login_code_id and a list of (login_purpose_type, cnt) as one column, you can obtain it like in one go (but it might be slow for the large data set:

```
CREATE TABLE summary_2 
SELECT login_code_id, group_concat(cnt) AS info 
FROM ( SELECT login_code_id,
concat("(", login_purpose_type,",", count(login_code_id),")") AS cnt 
FROM <old_table_name> 
GROUP BY login_code_id, login_purpose_type) s 
GROUP BY login_code_id ;
```

This will give you a table like:

```
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| login_code_id   | info                      |
+-----------------+---------------------------+
| A               | (maintenance,3),(review,2)|
| B               | (scan,2),(review,3)       |
| C               | (terminate,1)             |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Or you might use the first table as an intermediate and create summary_2 from the previous summary table:

```
CREATE TABLE summary_2 
SELECT login_code_id, group_concat(cnt) AS info FROM ( 
SELECT login_code_id, concat("(", login_purpose_type,",", cnt,")") AS cnt 
FROM summary ) s 
GROUP BY login_code_id ;
```